# error c2871: 'std' a namespace with this name does not exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

In my project I have disabled pre-compiled headers.
The following is code sample..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Getfilelist.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Getfilelist fl;
    int i = fl.GetFList("J:\\EDUCATION\\Mine\\seminar\\seminar-1");
    getch();
return 0;
}
```

And when I am using "using namespace std;" an error is being displayed

```
error c2871: 'std' a namespace with this name does not exist
```

Comment: Why do you expect `namespace std` to be defined when you only include C headers?

Comment: **What all I want to know is reason for this error.** I have done many projects by including the headers and namespace std, but this is for first time I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

You should `#include <cstdio>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for solution. But I have been using VS2008 since 1 year, and never got this problem before with the namespace 'std'. May I know reason for this error

Comment: stdio.h may not wrap functions in namespace std for backward compatibility.

Comment: @user3615925 You've always included, possibly indirectly, at least one header that introduces the "std" namespace.